# Memory Leak Where is it

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, magicknet

I'm getting an out of memory exception while looping through images. It happens after about 500 images.

if I try to run the same code through a parallel loop it only makes it through about 5 images.

It usually seems to slow down before throwing the out of memory exception

Here is my code. I'm using MagickNet

```
public static void PreProductionProcessing(DirectoryInfo dirInfo)
{
    var tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\bar.csv", true);

    tw.WriteLine("Filename, Alpha Channel Removed, Dpi Changed, Resized");
    foreach (var currentFile in dirInfo.GetFiles("*.tif"))
    {
        var alphaChannelRemoved = false;
        var resized = false;
        var DpiChanged = false;

        Image img = null;

        MemoryStream ms = null;

        try
        {
            img = new Image(currentFile.FullName);

            if (img.Matte)
            {
                ms = RemoveAlphaChanell(currentFile.FullName);
                img = new Image(ms);
                alphaChannelRemoved = true;
            }

            if (img.Density.x_res < 300)
            {
                img.Density = new Image.Resolution(300, 300);
                DpiChanged = true;
            }

            if (img.Size.Width != 1875)
            {
                var newSize = img.Size;
                double resizeRatio = (double)newSize.Width / (double)1875;

                newSize.Width = Convert.ToInt16(img.Size.Width / resizeRatio);
                newSize.Height = Convert.ToInt16(img.Size.Height / resizeRatio);

                img.Resize(newSize);
                resized = true;
            }

            using (var filestream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(@"C:\OutFolder", currentFile.Name), FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                img.Write(filestream, "tif");
            }

            tw.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", currentFile.Name, alphaChannelRemoved, DpiChanged, resized);

            tw.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tw.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", currentFile.Name, e.Message);
            tw.Flush();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (img != null)
            {
                img.Dispose();
                img = null;
            }

            if (ms != null)
                ms.Dispose();

            Magick.Term();
        }
    }
}

static MemoryStream RemoveAlphaChanell(string source)
{
    Bitmap old = new Bitmap(source);
    Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(old.Width, old.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(temp);
    g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
    var rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, new Size(old.Width, old.Height));
    g.DrawImage(old, rect);
    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    temp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Tiff);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    old.Dispose();
    temp.Dispose();
    g.Dispose();

    return stream;
}
```

I'm not sure if the memory leak is within MagickNet or if anyone can see anything in my code that is causing this issue.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try using a profiler?

Comment: You should wrap the `MemoryStream ms` in a `using` if possible. Aside from that, you will probably need a memory profilier, Visual Studio has one.

Comment: @L.B In the `finally` block of the `try` block that it's initialized in.

Comment: You should wrap both the `MemoryStream` and the `Image` in a `using` block.

Comment: I apologize to who I upset with my question and I would appreciate it if you would let me know what about my question upset you enough to down vote it. Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `img.Matte` is true, you replace the image in the `img` variable with a new image. The previous image is never disposed.

Dispose the previous image before you replace it:

```
        if (img.Matte)
        {
            img.Dispose();
            ms = RemoveAlphaChanell(currentFile.FullName);
            img = new Image(ms);
            alphaChannelRemoved = true;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this appears to have done the trick. Not sure what I was thinking. I really appreciate the help.